# ui-router controller or angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router for routing my app. On ui-router I can define controller like

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    })
    .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
    })
```

here you can see the controller definition on ui-router state object.

My question is, what is more common, define an angular controller or ui-router controller?

```
angular.module('controllerExample', [])
  .controller('SettingsController2', ['$scope', SettingsController2]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'What's more common' is a very broad question, but.

There are few things to consider:

1. What type of state and how nested is it (If its a nested state that only displays a bulk of data that's might be fine)
2. How large the controller is? (2-3 lines of logic can be handled inline)
3. How do you structure your app?

In the end, a better practice is to put all in an organized 1 spot and not splitting your controller definition, so if to choose from both approaches, **don't define your controller inline**.

Comment: They are no any rules, that I can use it?

Comment: In general, I recommend to go over this style guide - (very popular) - https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

Answer (score 1):

I could not say what is more common, just why to use the second approach.

Firstly, if we declare the controller as `SettingsController2` (object/function), we can use it multiple times.

Secondly, this approach creates a real type, which could be later easily trakced (found) once you observe the pefromance tools (memory profiler)

Finally, if we will use some `JS++` like `Typescript` or `AtScript`, we can easily use *inheritance* and even other features...

So do not use inline def, if possible